# Prepared Statement not working even though the same query returns a row when run in toad

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, toad

I am trying to get a row from DB using preparedStatement using a code which somewhat looks like this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
Connection con = new Connection ()  //pseudo Code added here
String query = "select * from abc where a=? and b=? and c=?";

preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);

preparedStatement.setString(1,"x");

preparedStatement.setString(2,"y");

preparedStatement.setString(3,String.valueOf('Z'));

ResultSet resultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if(resultset.next() == false)
{
  throw new exception("No records fetched");
}
```

but the following query when executed via TOAD, returns a row:

```
select * from abc where a='x' and b='y' and c='z';
```

What am I doing wrong here? (The third condition in where clause is a char).

Comment: z or Z? and why you dont use `preparedStatement.setString(3,"z");`?

Comment: please write the connection related code and library which was imported in class

Comment: When you say 'prepared statement not working' do you mean you get an error, or do you mean that you dont get any results?

Comment: Am not getting any rows using prepared statement but the same query in TOAD returns a row.

Answer (score 1):

The two queries are different, in TOAD you're issuing

```
select * from abc where a='x' and b='y' and c='z'
```

whereas from your prepared statement you're doing the equivalent of:

```
select * from abc where a='x' and b='y' and c='Z'
```

`z` is not the same as `Z`

You don't need to specify Oracle `CHAR` parameters as Java `char` in the setParameter, so changing

```
preparedStatement.setString(3,String.valueOf('Z'));
```

to either

```
preparedStatement.setString(3,"z");
```

or

```
preparedStatement.setString(3,String.valueOf('z'));
```

will probably work.

Comment: Then I would check the connection settings, are you sure that you are using the same user/schema for the connection in TOAD and from your code?